# Changing menu buttons to normal buttons

Tags: java, android

```
            case R.id.Delete_Contact:

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteContact)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            mydb.deleteContact(id_To_Update);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog d = builder.create();
            d.setTitle("Are you sure");
            d.show();

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

How can i use this in an button click event ? This works when clicking menu  button

Comment: By setting a `View.OnClickListener` on a `Button` and use the same code in `onClick`

Answer (score 2):

//Initialize your button

//Set Click Listener to that like below

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
            //Perform Some Action
            //common method to be called
            deleteConfirmation();
});

public void deleteConfirmation(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteContact)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        mydb.deleteContact(id_To_Update);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog d = builder.create();
        d.setTitle("Are you sure");
        d.show();

      }
   });

}
```

> You should use common method as you want same code to be executed multiple times. This is just a suggestion